# Why can't I use for in loop on a map object

Tags: javascript

For my own benefit I am going through each of the built in structured objects in Javascript and in particular I am trying out each of the basic 'for' loops so that I have grokked what works where.

In the case of Map, I noticed that the for/in loop is silent. I would have expected it to return the key values for each entry into the map.

```js
let map = new Map([[1, 1], ["two", "two"]]);
map.set("three", 3); // Instead of add
console.log(`map has three = ${map.has("three")}`);
console.log(`map has size ${map.size}`);
// no 'for loop' because map uses keys instead of index numbers
for (let key in map) console.log(`for key ${key} in map ${map}`); // <<< This does not return??
for (let value of map) console.log(`for ${value} of ${map}`); 
map.forEach((value, key, localScopeCopyOfMap) => console.log(`forEach value ${value} in map 
${[...localScopeCopyOfMap]}`));
```

Why does this not return anything?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach

Comment: That is about as useful as an ashtray on a motorcycle :) It is referencing the forEach method which I already know is a better way to do this but I am curious in this question about why the for/in loop is not returning anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for...in` iterates over enumerable properties of an object. The keys in a map are not enumerable properties (though a map, like all objects, *can* have enumerable properties). For one thing, they can be of any type, not just strings, as with JavaScript objects, which have historically stood in for maps.

`for...of` iterates over an [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols), which is how the `Map` yields up its keys/values for iteration.

On this statement...

> ```
> for (let key in map) console.log(`for key ${key} in map ${map}`); // <<< This does not return??
> ```

Your comment "does not return" doesn't really make sense. None of these "return", they invoke a block zero or more times. In this case, zero, because the map has no enumerable properties.

If you do `map.foo = "bar"`, then `for...in` will iterate once, and print out `"for key foo in map [object Map]"`. This is *not* the same as inserting a new key/value pair into the map: It defines a new property on the object which exists completely separately from the map's contents.

Comment: Thankyou. I was being stupid. This is a fundamental thing I have been misunderstanding for years.